# Can I receive a message, prepare its response and send a message in a context of a single JMS transaction?

Tags: java, transactions, jms

Studying to a exam I just found a question I can't answer either after looking in the web. The question is:

"Can a server receive a request using a JMS message, prepare its response (e.g access a database) and send the reply using again, JMS, i the scope of a single JMS transaction?"

I know we can send a transacted message or receive a message in the context of a transaction. I know we can group several message sends and receives in a single transaction protecting the whole interaction. However, JMS is designed to be asynchronous. So in theory I would need to have a transaction to send the message to the queue and a transaction to receive the message from the queue. Am I right or is it possible to have a SINGLE transaction for a send and receive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, transacted receivers can be implemented in jMS.** They are implemented by controlling the acknowledgemode of the communication: if all transactional operations are successful, the received message will be acknowledged to the broker, but in case of failure it does not happen, so the message can get redelivered.

[This article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26137&seqNum=8) explains this in more details:

> **Both message producers and message consumers may use transacted
>   sessions.** [...]
>
> With message consumers, transacted sessions control message
>   acknowledgment. The consumer can receive multiple messages just like
>   the CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE mode. When the associated transaction is
>   committed, the JMS implementation acknowledges all messages received
>   in the associated transaction. If the transaction aborts, the JMS
>   implementation returns the messages to the associated queue or topic.